# Problem in OpenLayers 3 with mapserver-cgi

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, wms, mapserver

I want to form a map using mapserver-cgi, but it does not fit the basemap (OSM).

```
msLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
   source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
   url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?mode=map&map=/var/www/trdem1.map',
   params: {
            'LAYERS': 'trdem_4326_ov20',
             'TRANSPARENT': 'true'
             },
             projection: 'EPSG:3857', 
             type: 'mapserver'
            })
  });
```

mapserver-cgi actually creates an image

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your issue.  You state that `mapserver-cgi actually creates an image` as if this is itself the problem, but that's correct, when mapserver-cgi acts as a WMS it's meant to provide images, that's what WMS do.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

One thing you have wrong for a WMS is the inclusion of the `mode=map&` parameter in your URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `projection` option is wrong. The option tells `openlayers` the CRS for the *layer*. It is not telling the layer about the map CRS.

The layer CRS seems to be EPSG:4326, so I think your code should look like this:

```
msLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          ...
          projection: 'EPSG:4326', 
          ...
      })
  });
```